# How to ask user whether to exit or keep running?

Tags: python

I'm new to coding and this is my first post here so I hope I am doing it correctly.

I am learning Python and trying to do the "FizzBuzz" program. I am trying to implement a string asking the user if they want to continue, with a "y" or "n" response, if "y" it keeps running, if "n" it simply says 'Thank you for playing".

I just cannot seem to get the latter response to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code (from PyCharm):

```py
valid_input = True


def number_game():
    num = int(input("Please type a whole number "))

    if (num % 3 == 0) and (num % 5 == 0):
        print("Fizz Buzz")
    elif num % 3 == 0:
        print("Fizz")
    elif num % 5 == 0:
        print("Buzz")
    else:
        print(num)

    cont = input("Continue? Y or N").lower()
    if cont == "y":
        number_game()
    else:
        print("Thank you for playing")


# Should I use a while loop somewhere in code instead?

    # while valid_input:
    #     number_game()
    #     print("\n")
```

Comment: short answer: your code is valid, but yes, I'd recommend to use a loops, if you can avoid recursion, in general. This way, you don't clutter what is called "the stack".I'll others elaborate or yourself searching about it.  Also, I also find loops a bit more readable, but that's my opinion.

Comment: your code does exactly what you claim to want it to do ...

Comment: Thank you both. When I run the code in PyCharm I get nothing. It doesn't say "Please type a whole number ".

Comment: Hi @Pesto you commented out the last part. You need to invoke the function somewhere. I can't answer you anymore though...

Comment: Ok, makes sense - thank you! I never wrote in the last line of code to start it all: 
number_game()